# PYTHON: How do i merge two dictionaries inside a list in the most pythonic way

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list

```
result = [
    {
        "name": "James",
        "label":"Student",
        "class": 18
    },
    {
        "name": "Jacob",
        "label":"Professor",
        "class": 18
    },
    {
        "name": "Jeff",
        "label":"Student",
        "class": 19
    }
]
```

and I want to merge two dictionaries with the same class

I have tried:

```
res = [{item['label']:item['name'],'class':item['class']} for item in result]

print(res)

>>[{'Student': 'James', 'class': 18}, {'Professor': 'Jacob', 'class': 18}, {'Student': 'Jeff', 'class': 19}]
```

sample of desired output:

```
result = [
    {
        "Student": "James",
        "Professor": "Jacob",
        "class": 18
    },
    {
        "Student": "Jeff",
        "class": 19
    }
]
```

can someone help me on this one please? Thank you in advance

Comment: Will the `class` always be the key to join different elements in your list on?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Your target data structure is probably wrong. It only allows a single student per class. You would want the value associated with the `"Student"` key to be a list of strings. You would probably want to change the key to be named `"Students"`.

Comment: To the person who downvoted this question - atleast mention the reason why it was downvoted and provide the oppurtunity to the questioner to modify it. Simply downvoting without comments is not going to help a new comer. You need to understand that it was easier for people who joined earlier to get up votes for their questions and answers. Now it is very difficult because many who joined earlier had already asked basic questions or answered those basic questions and they are still earning votes from those. For a new comer it is really difficult to get votes. Have some consideration for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function called, `merge` and create a dictionary `merged` to keep track of visited classes, then whenever a record with the same class in occurred we simply update the dictionary for that class with the key-value pair of `label-name`:

```
def merge(dicts):
    merged = {}
    for d in dicts:
        key = d['class']
        if key in merged:
            merged[key][d['label']] = d['name']
        else:
            merged[key] = {'class': d['class'], d['label']: d['name']}
    return list(merged.values())
```

Result:

```
# print(merge(result))

[{'Student': 'James', 'class': 18, 'Professor': 'Jacob'}, {'Student': 'Jeff', 'class': 19}]
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But have to sort dicts by class. Other than that, PERFECT!! Thank you

Comment: @jpaulc Made a few changes to make algorithm more efficient, check out the edited answer.